# How to compare two cell strings to list str

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a formula or vba to compare a cell string to a list of strings and populate a column with true/false based on sequence in the list.

[image: example]

If string in "Stopped" column comes after the string in "Fix" column based on the sequence column, then populate "True". If the string from "Stopped" comes before "Fix" in sequence or matches, then populate false.

Answer (score 0):

Use MATCH to compare their positions in the Sequence column:

```
=MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$7,0)>MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$7,0)
```

[image]